# How to remove a piece of an observableArray inside a loop with knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an array of objects inside an observableArray called `emails`. Each of the emails in the array has an associated checkbox to select multiple messages at one time.  In order to apply a function to multiple items, I loop through the emails to see if they're checked, and if they are they run the function:

```
self.deleteSelected = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.emails().length; i++) {
        if (self.emails()[i].selected() == true) {
            ** what would go here **
        }
    }
}
```

The loop I have there works exactly how I want it to because I have it being used with other functions, but I cannot seem to get the right function to delete the index out of the observableArray. If tried `.remove()` and `.splice` but I couldn't get either of them to work.

Any idea what I need to add to that function to get it to delete the corresponding index in the array as it loops through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are incurring in problems deleting elements from the array you are traversing. As an alternative approach, why don't you build a new array with the items you want to keep?

Something along these lines should work:

```
self.deleteSelected = function() {

    var emails = self.emails(),
        emailsLength = emails.length,
        emailsToKeep = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < emailsLength; i++) {
        if (emails[i].selected() !== true) {
            emailsToKeep.push(emails[i]);
        }
    }

    self.emails(emailsToKeep);
}
```

By the way, replacing your `observableArray` in one single operation it's also better from a performances point of view: everytime you would use `splice()` or `remove()` you would cause the associated piece of DOM to rebuild completely, this way this happens only once.

Note that in my code there are two other minor performance improvements:

- I cached in variables the observables instead of retrieving them every time
- I stored in a variable the array `length` instead of accessing the property in every for loop.

Comment: Awesome, this works, and I like the improvements. Thanks for the explanations as well, I like to know why!

Comment: Thanks, if you liked the answer/you found it useful you can upvote/accept it.